# I lost my pem file for one of my EC2 instance. No luck in restoring the instance by replacing the authorized key in root volume of this instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pem, ec2-ami, key-pair

I lost my pem file. So i followed the steps given in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8jXE-_hdfg to restore the instance by changing the authorized_keys in root volume. Once it attached the instance in "dev/xvda" (root). I am still facing issue in connecting to this ec2 instance with a new key pair.

Description in ec2 instance still shows old KP name. I am getting below message while trying to connect as "ec2-user" with new KP.

[image]

Comment: Just use AWS Session manager to connect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aws session manager to login into the instance. Once you are logged in then you can get your .pem file.
Have a look here [How to access EC2 Instance even if PEM file is lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52560096/how-to-access-ec2-instance-even-if-pem-file-is-lost)